# PHP mysql edit database entries

Tags: php, edit

so i have two php file the first one

```
  <?php
  include"db.inc.php";//database connection
  $order = "SELECT * FROM notes";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ("<tr><td>$row[Name]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Comment]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Timestamp]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[Timestamp]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
  }
  ?>
```

and the second one.

```
  <?php
  include "db.inc.php";//database connection

  $order = "SELECT * FROM note 

  where Timestamp='id'";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
```

the is and **id=$row[Timestamp]** in the first file and **where Timestamp='id'";** how do i get the value of id in the second file to equal the id in the first file. thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that's utterly basic PHP and http processing. This is something you should learn on your own. We're here to help, not be your teachers.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: What is the table name "notes" or "note"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_GET` here

```
include "db.inc.php";//database connection

$id = $_GET['id'];
$order = "SELECT * FROM note where Timestamp='$id'";
```

Start using `PDO` OR `MySQLi` with prepared statement, this code is full with `SQL Injection`.

**Edit**

In third file access the variable using `$_POST`

```
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: thanks Yogeth that worked. however I have a third file that uses id again and the $GET['id']; doesnt work on it

Comment: @user2341207 Accept the answer if it solved your problem.  :) . And what it means `however I have a third file`?

Comment: @user2341207 show the code how you pass from second file to third file and how you tried to retrieve in third file.

Comment: my third file

<?php
//edit_data.php
include "db.inc.php";
$order = "UPDATE note 
          SET Name='$name', 
              Comment='$comment' 
          WHERE 
       Timestamp='$id'";
mysql_query($order);
header("location:edit.php");
?>

Comment: sending it  
<form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
id: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id"?>">
 Name:<input type="text" Name="name" >
 Comment:<input type="text" name="comment"  >
 
<input type="submit">

Comment: @user2341207 paste your second and third file code in your question not in comment.

Comment: thank you so much. I am getting there. finally when i go <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id"?>">  how do i make value equal the variable i have in $id.

Answer (score 0):

- Put the code in second file as function.
- Include the Second file to "edit_form.php" and Call the function of
  Second file from "edit_form.php" passing value of $id (obtained from
  $_Get['id'] ).